# Using php include with a echo value

Tags: php, mysqli

I asked a question late last night and trying to work out a way to fix my issue

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18423781/displaying-data-from-two-tables-depending-on-value-of-one-row)

I included the link to the question encase it was relevant to this question

I am trying to display data from a file named example.php

in example.php i have the following code

```
<?php

//include database connection
include 'db_connect.php';



$query = "select id, name, surname
        from contacts
        where id='".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_REQUEST['id'])."'
        limit 0,1";

$result = $mysqli->query( $query );
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();

$id = $row['id'];
$name = $row['name'];
$surname = $row['surname'];

?>
<?php echo$name; ?><br>
<?php echo$surname; ?>
```

so if i visited my page by going to example.php?id=100 it would display the client with the id off 100

but what i am trying to do is display this file depending on another table.

i have a table named repairs and in there is a column named client_id with is the same as the id of the contacts table.

I have tried to display the file by doing this.

```
<?php include'example.php?id=echo$client_id;'?>
```

But this did not work please advise me what the right code is and why this is wrong.

Comment: why was this question marked down?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
<?php
$_REQUEST['id'] = $client_id;
 include'example.php';

?>
```

Comment: thanks :) how would i use this is this code? echo "<td>your code</td>";

Comment: just echo the results in example.php `echo $name.'<br>'.$surname;`